# Connecting to QuickBooks using API

Tags: api, sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I need some guidelines here. I am creating an online booking system for my client that interfaces with QuickBooks on their internal network (desktop QuickBooks, not online).

Do I need to go the full "publish app" route? I do not wish to sell this app in the marketplace. This is merely a custom booking system designed and paid for by the client. It seems like I need to "publish" the app in the marketplace for them to be able to use it.

Are there ways around this?

Comment: Sorry, just for more clarification:

Client is running quickbooks enterprise 13 on their local pc's (Terminal Server).

I am creating an online (www) booking system (Asp.net), that need to interface with their Quickbooks.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I have started looking at the quickbooks API, but as mentioned above, I do not wish to "publish" this solution as an accessible App in your market place.

Should I rather use the SDK with web connector, or can I still use the Quickbooks API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Update 06/23/2015** - To connect to a desktop QuickBooks installation the SDK with the Web Connector is now the only recommended approach.  Intuit is removing Intuit Partner Platform (IPP) integration to desktop QuickBooks.

For the SDK/Web Connector, you don't need to go through any publication process or anything like that. Just build the solution, and connector your client.

There's a pretty good overview of [how the QuickBooks web connector works](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_Overview) on our [QuickBooks wiki](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks).

The [QuickBooks SDK](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/get-started) download also includes a huge PDF with detailed documentation about how to implement SDK/Web Connector applications as well.